# Poils et cheveux : pourquoi deux mots différents ?

Tags: étymologie, vocabulaire, comparaison-de-langues

Le français a deux mots bien distincts pour désigner les *poils* (humains ou animaux, sur tout le corps) et les *cheveux* (spécifiquement humains, sur la tête). Comment ceci se fait-il ? L'anglais, par exemple, n'a qu'un seul mot: *hair*.

Comment: Salut Knu. Désolé, j'ai voté pour fermer ta question comme "off topic", parce que tu n'as pas demandé sur le Français, mais sur les autres langues.

Comment: @Alenanno justement ce serait idiot de demander sur EL&U par exemple car pour eux ce ne sont juste que les poils du crane. Seuls ceux qui peuvent appréhender cette nuance sont susceptibles de pouvoir expliquer son occurrence. Le français fait partie d'un groupe restreint de langue qui fait cette distinction. Poser la question dans l'autre sens n'aurait aucun intérêt (ce serait trop évident).

Comment: Je n'ai pas dit que ta question es idiote (N.B. je ne veux pas faire cette discussion personelle), mais qu'elle n'est pas sur le Français. Tu as demandé "*Pourquoi certaines langues ne font-elles pas la distinction entre les poils et les cheveux?*", le Français fait cette distinction, donc ta question n'est pas "on topic". Je suis le seul qui a voté, donc si les autres ne seront pas d'accord, ta question restera ouverte.

Comment: Pour que la question soit de nouveau "on-topic", la changer en "Pourquoi le français fait-il la différence entre poil et cheveux ?" pourrait fonctionner, je pense. D'ailleurs, étoffer le titre et les exemples serait un énorme plus.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Les mots *[poil](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/poil)* et *[cheveu](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cheveu)* sont (probablement) étymologiquement apparentés. Ils dérivent respectivement des mots latins *[pilus](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pilus#Latin)* et *[capillus](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/capillus#Latin)* de mêmes sens. Ce sont des dérivations populaires ; on reconnaît mieux les mots latins dans les dérivés savants tels que *[pilosité](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pilosit%C3%A9)* ou *[capillaire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/capillaire)*.

Il est tentant de voir le mot latin *capillus* comme une contraction de *capitis pilus*, qui signifierait « poil de tête ». Cette étymologie est contestée : la ressemblance entre les deux mots pourrait être une coïncidence. On pourra pour approfondir ce point lire ces articles :

- Josef Brüch. *Capillus* und *pilus*. *Indogermanische Forschungen* 63, 1958. doi:10.1515/9783110243048.228
- Martti Nyman. The Family Resemblance of Latin *caput* and *capillus* (and what can be gleaned from it). *Indogermanische Forschungen* 82, 1977. doi:10.1515/9783110243246
- Martti Nyman. Positing a Lautgesetz: Latin *capillus*, *pullus* and kindred issues. *Folia Linguistica Historica* III/I, 1982.

La plupart des langues latines ont deux mots différents et apparentés pour désigner les poils sur la tête d'un être humain et les poils d'un animal. En revanche, les langues germaniques ont un seul mot pour tous les types de poils. Si l'on en croit [le Wiktionnaire](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hair), aucun des deux camps n'est franchement majoritaire : certaines langues ont un seul mot, d'autres ont deux mots apparentés, d'autres encore deux mots différents (voire plus : il peut y avoir une distinction entre les poils capitaux humains, les poils du reste du corps, et les poils des animaux qui en sont couverts).

Et c'est sans compter les *[cils](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cil)* et les *[sourcils](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sourcil)*, tandis qu'il n'y a pas de mot spécifique pour les poils de barbe, les poils pubiens, et autres lieux pileux du corps humain. Il y a par contre des mots spécifiques pour les (ou certains) poils de certains animaux : *[crinière](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/crini%C3%A8re)*, *[laine](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/laine)*...

Comment: En détournant ma question tu as quand même réussi à répondre à la précédente.

Comment: L'utilisation de *hair* (au singulier) comme d'un ensemble plutot que de désigner *les poils* ou *les cheveux* correspondrait peut-être mieux à *chevelure* ou *toison* (voir les semi-apparentés *pelage* ou *pelisse*) ? Tous les mots d'une langue ne correspondant pas à tous les mots d'une autre, on peut en effet difficilement dire qu'il "manque" un terme anglophone pour désigner individuellement l'un des éléments de l'ensemble (le poil, le cheveu, le cil, etc.)